# Error accesing union members inside a union

Tags: c++, unions, arduino-c++

I´m having problem accesing this union:

```
typedef union{ 
  struct{    
    uint8_t SA : 8; //! Source Address   
    union { //! Protocol Data Unit
      struct {      
        uint8_t SPECIFIC : 8;     
        uint8_t FORMAT : 8;
      } ;
      uint16_t PDU2 ;
    };    
    uint8_t DP : 1; //! Data Page    
    uint8_t Reserved : 1;  //! Reserved = 0   
    uint8_t PRIORITY : 3;   //! Priority   
    uint8_t Reserved1 : 3;  //! Reserved = 0
  };  
  uint32_t word;  //single 32-bit word
}  J1939_ID
```

Executing the next in an ESP32

```
J1939_ID J1939_RxId;
        J1939_RxId.word = 0x11223344;
        Serial.println(J1939_RxId.word, HEX);
        Serial.println(J1939_RxId.SA, HEX);
        Serial.println(J1939_RxId.PDU2, HEX);
        Serial.println(J1939_RxId.FORMAT, HEX);
        Serial.println(J1939_RxId.SPECIFIC, HEX);
```

PDU2 is 0x1122 instead of what I wanted 0x2233,
the same for FORMAT(0x22) and SPECIFIC (0x33)

I can't see what is wrong, can anyone help me please?

EDIT:
the solution was adding "**attribute**((packed))" for the unions

```
typedef union{ 
  struct{    
    uint8_t SA : 8; //! Source Address   
    union { //! Protocol Data Unit
      struct {      
        uint8_t SPECIFIC : 8;     
        uint8_t FORMAT : 8;
      } ;
      uint16_t PDU2 ;
    }__attribute__((packed));    
    uint8_t DP : 1; //! Data Page    
    uint8_t Reserved : 1;  //! Reserved = 0   
    uint8_t PRIORITY : 3;   //! Priority   
    uint8_t Reserved1 : 3;  //! Reserved = 0
  };  
  uint32_t word;  //single 32-bit word
} __attribute__((packed)) J1939_ID
```

Comment: Please only tag one language that you are using. C unions are different from C++ unions.

Comment: And if that's arduino (guessing by `Serial`), also make sure to use proper tags.

Comment: `struct` types can have alignment padding between members. There is probably 1 byte of padding between `SA` and `PDU2`. Look up how to declare a "packed" `struct` type in your compiler documentation. Check the size of `J1939_ID` to confirm. You want 4, but the compiler has probably made it size 8 (1 byte of padding between `SA` and `PDU2` plus 3 bytes of padding after `Reserved1`).

Comment: yes, it is 8 bytes the size of J1939_ID, I added  __attribute__((packed)) and now its working as expected, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You have a little endian machine. As such, `RxId.word` looks like

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 44 | 33 | 22 | 11 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Your compiler uses "normal padding conventions", so your struct is closer to the following (with some irrelevant details omitted):

```c
struct {
   uint8_t SA;          // Aligned to an offset divisible by 1.
   uint8_t __padding1;
   uint16_t PDU2;       // Aligned to an offset divisible by 2.
   uint8_t flags;       // Aligned to an offset divisible by 1.
   uint8_t __padding2;  
}                       // Size must be divisible by 2 (largest of above).
```

Putting the two together, we get

```c
struct { 
   uint8_t  SA;         // 0x44
   uint8_t  __padding;  // 0x33
   uint16_t PDU2;       // 0x1122
   uint8_t  flags;      // 0x00 or uninitialized, not sure.
}
```

If you want to continue using unions, you will need to convert the word from native endianness to big-endian (e.g. using `htonl`), or alter the order of the fields in the struct. And you will also need to tell your compiler to create a "packed" struct (i.e. omit padding).